# Use a pytest fixture to download data once, but use new copies for each test

Tags: python, caching, pytest, fixtures

I have test code that downloads a set of images, does some processing on them, and asserts that the processing worked as expected:

```py
@pytest.fixture
def image_dir(tmp_path):
    test_imgs = [
        # ... list of img URLs
    ]
    for idx, im_url in enumerate(test_imgs):
        urllib.request.urlretrieve(im_url, tmp_path / f"{idx}.png")
    yield tmp_path

def test_op_A(image_dir: Path):
    for im_path in image_dir.iterdir():
        # load the image
        # modify the image
        # save the image back to disk

    # assert that the modification worked as expected

def test_op_B(image_dir: Path):
    for im_path in image_dir.iterdir():
        # load the image
        # modify the image
        # save the image back to disk

    # assert that the modification worked as expected

# ... more tests with a similar format
```

This works but is incredibly slow. I suspect that this is because the images are downloaded anew for each test.

Is there a clean way to create the temporary directory once, cache it, and use a copy of the directory for each test? This way each test can modify the images as desired, without influencing the other tests and while remaining performant.

Comment: do the images modify and save it to the same place? if the answer is no then you can session scope the fixture, if the answer is yes then there will need to be some extra work done

Comment: @gold_cy Yes, the images are modified in-place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So a possible solution to achieve this would make use of [`pytest_sessionstart`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/reference.html#pytest.hookspec.pytest_sessionstart) and [`pytest_sessionfinish`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/reference.html#pytest.hookspec.pytest_sessionfinish). We will also use a fixture in order to copy files over.

A general break down of the flow we hope to achieve is the following:

1. Download the necessary files before test collection
2. Have the fixture copy the necessary files to a temporary location
3. After the tests complete, delete the files from the cached location

Place the following two hooks in your `conftest.py` in the root directory where your tests reside.

```
from pathlib import Path
from tempfile import TemporaryDirectory

def pytest_sessionstart(session):
    test_imgs = [
        # ... list of img URLs
    ]
    td = TemporaryDirectory()
    tmp_path = Path(td.name)

    for idx, im_url in enumerate(test_imgs):
        urllib.request.urlretrieve(im_url, tmp_path / f"{idx}.png")

    session.__IMAGE_CACHE = tmp_path


def pytest_sessionfinish(session, exitstatus):
    # remove the cached images
    session.__IMAGE_CACHE.cleanup()
```

Now that we have the images cached in a location, we can have our fixture copy them over for every test instead of having to download them.

```
from shutil import copytree

@pytest.fixture
def image_dir(tmp_path, request):
    session = request.session
    # copy the data from our cache to the temp location for the test
    copytree(session.__IMAGE_CACHE, tmp_path)
    yield tmp_path
```